# Console logs in Mac

Tags: mac

A user had reported an error while using my application. This was a month back but unfortunately, I can get to his system only now. This is a Macbook Air 10.6.5. In Console, I don't see messages which are older than a month. Is there a way I can get them ?. Are they archived off somewhere ?.

Comment: If you look to the left navigation pane in Console, do you see an expandable tree named /Library/Logs ? I have an application that crashed in early July...

Comment: yes I searched at all places in the UI but could not find any thing which was older than a month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since at least Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard and possibly earlier, Mac OS X logging uses what's known as the "Apple System Logger" (ASL) subsystem, which stores all log messages in a database, and *also* routes some log messages to the traditional flat text file logs like system.log and kernel.log.

On my 10.6.8 system, it looks like the default time to live for ASL database records is 7 days, but I think it used to be longer, so maybe you're lucky and maybe in 10.6.5 it was longer.  If not, at least you can learn how to change the default time to live or archiving settings so you can get older messages.

You can query the ASL database with the `syslog` command. See the `syslog(1)` man page and the related man pages including `syslogd(8)`, `asl(3)`, `asl.conf(5)`, and `aslmanager(8)`.